# Quotes breaking code in javascript onclick event using Jquery append

Tags: jquery, append

I am  trying to pass two arguments in the on click javascript function. I need to enclose the the arguments in quotes. when i enclose it in single quotes it breaks the quote that starts from image and when i use double it breaks the quotes in front of javascript. how do i enclose it that it doesn't break my code?

```
$("#Div").append('<img id ="myImage" src ="/images/myimage.png"  onclick="javascript:myfunction('addnew',$("#field").val())"/> Error.')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
$("#Div").append( $( "<img>", {

    id: "myImage",

    src: "/images/myimage.png",

    click: function() {
        myfunction( 'addnew', $("#field").val() );
    }

}), " Error." );
```

Comment: I am trying to use this code on a span tag and the click event does not work . my code :
$("#error").append($("<span>",{
            id:"edit",
            title: action,
            click:function(){
             Edit(action,$('#field').val() );
             } 
             }), errMsg);

Comment: @user829982 it's likely the `Edit` part that's not working, put `click: function(){console.log("test");}` to test if the click event is not working.

Comment: the console does not add test when i use the span tag only when i use the img tag. it does not seem that the edit function is not working

Comment: @user829982 did you realize that `errMsg` is not inside the `span`, but is a separate `text` node? So clicking that text is not same as clicking the span. Try `$("<span>", {text: errMsg})` to make the text go inside the `span`..

Answer (score 2):

You will have to escape the quotes with a backslash, as such:

```
$("#Div").append('<img id ="myImage" src ="/images/myimage.png"  onclick="javascript:myfunction(\'addnew\',$("#field").val())"/> Error.')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you need to escape the apostrophe with `\`:

```
$("#Div").append('<img id ="myImage" src ="/images/myimage.png" onclick="javascript:myfunction(\'addnew\',$("#field").val())"/> Error.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape the single quotes around `\'addnew\'`:

```
$("#Div").append('<img id ="myImage" src ="/images/myimage.png"  onclick="javascript:myfunction(\'addnew\',$("#field").val())"/> Error.')
```